# Ajax post to ASP.net MVC controller - object properties are null

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've got an ajax post being constructed like this:

```
var myData = [
    {
        id: "a",
        name: "Name 1"
    },
    {
        id: "b",
        name: "Name 2"
    }
];

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/myurl/myAction',
    data: { items: myData },
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function (err) {
        alert("error - " + err);
    }
});
```

And an MVC controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MyAction(MyClass[] items)
{

}
```

`MyClass` is just a simple representation of the data:

```
public class MyClass {
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public string Id {get; set; }
}
```

When the javascript makes the post request, the controller action does indeed receive 2 items, however the properties (id, name) in these items are null.

Checking the request in fiddler, the body looks like this:

```
Name                 | Value
items[0][Name]       | Name 1
items[0][Id]         | a
items[1][Name]       | Name 2
items[1][Id]         | b
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: Just a guess, maybe it's because the properties are lowercase in javascript and uppercase in C#.

Comment: No, it's not that. The JSON serializer is not case sensitive.

Comment: Another scenario where properties are null - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124405/json-object-properties-are-coming-as-null

Answer (score 65, accepted):

> Have I missed something?

Yes, take a look at the [following article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) to understand the correct wire format that the default model binder expects for binding collections. In other words, for this to work, instead of:

```
items[0][Name]       | Name 1
items[0][Id]         | a
items[1][Name]       | Name 2
items[1][Id]         | b
```

your payload should have looked like this:

```
items[0].Name       | Name 1
items[0].Id         | a
items[1].Name       | Name 2
items[1].Id         | b
```

Unfortunately with jQuery it can be quite frustrating to achieve this payload. For this reason I would recommend that you use a JSON payload if you want to send complex objects/arrays to your server with AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/myurl/myAction',
    data: JSON.stringify({ items: myData }),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    error: function (err) {
        alert("error - " + err);
    }
});
```

Things to notice:

- `data: JSON.stringify({ items: myData })` instead of `data: { items: myData }`
- Added `contentType: 'application/json'`
- Gotten rid of `dataType: 'json'`

Now your payload looks like this:

```
{"items":[{"id":"a","name":"Name 1"},{"id":"b","name":"Name 2"}]}
```

Comment: Took two hours of my time trying to figure out what was wrong with my code. Thanks dude!

Comment: This is probably obvious but also note that the `{ get; set; }` on your properties server side will also make or break this! That is all I was missing but this pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: @Ihan - you just saved what little sanity I had left.

Comment: i missed content type

Comment: how would you pass request verification token along with this request, AFAIK adding 'content-type' doesn't pass the token correctly.

Answer (score -4):

you can use this code to solve the problem :

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/myurl/myAction',
    data: { '': items },
    method: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (xhr, status, response) {
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, response) {
    }
});

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MyAction(IEnumerable<MyClass> items)
{

}
```