# JSON Object Properties are coming as NULL

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

I have Kendo UI grid in ASP.Net MVC. I am trying to pass `JSON` object to controller. Though I am getting an object in the controller, the properties are coming as `NULL` (FirstName, LastName). How can we correct it?

Note: The object is not null; but the properties are null in the object

**JSON**

```
   var NewPerson = new Object();
   NewPerson.FirstName = "A";
   NewPerson.LastName = "B";

   var json1 = { myPerson: NewPerson };
   return json1;
```

**JavaScript**

```
     $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
                transport: {

                    dataType: "json",
                    //,type: "POST"
                    read: {
                        url: "Home/GetItemsData",
                        data: function ()
                        {
                            var NewPerson = new Object();
                            NewPerson.FirstName = "A";
                            NewPerson.LastName = "B";

                            var json1 = { myPerson: NewPerson };
                            return json1;
                        }
                    }



                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            Program: {
                                ItemID: "number",
                            },
                            ItemDescription: { type: "string" }
                        }
                    },
                    total: "Total",
                    data: "Items"
                },
                serverPaging: true,
                serverSorting: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                pageSize: 5
            },
            scrollable: false,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            columns: [
                        { field: "ItemID", title: "Item Id", width: "70px" },
                        { field: "ItemDescription", title: "Item Description", width: "110px" }
            ]
        });
```

Controller

```
 public JsonResult GetItemsData(Person myPerson, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
    }
```

Comment: How query to server looks like in Firebug?

Comment: @NikolayFominyh I have resolved it and the network traffic is posted in the answer, below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue. For the benefit of others I will put the solution here.

The issue got resolved when I removed the NewPerson variable. Now I am directly assigning values to the myPerson. And the corresponding network traffic is listed below.

[image]

```
 var myPerson = {};
 myPerson.FirstName = "A";
 myPerson.LastName = "B";

 data: function () 
 {

    return myPerson;
 }
```

**UPDATE**

For getJSON Method, the syntax will be as shown below, as mentioned in [Better JSON data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746864/better-json-data-structure)

```
var searchCriteria = {};
searchCriteria.Accrual = "A";
searchCriteria.Brand = "B";

$.getJSON(url, searchCriteria
, function (data) {
    if (data.length) {
        alert('Success');
    }

});
```

---

Comment: References [haacked.com - Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547491/ajax-post-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-object-properties-are-null

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, your code is similar to this:

```
var x = function (){
  return "foo";
};
```

Here, `x` does not contain `foo`, it contains the function reference. You need to *execute* the function in order to get its return value:

```
var x = (function (){
  return "foo";
})();
```

Here, `x` does contain `foo`.